# Jquery selection by value not accepting the value stored in a variable

Tags: jquery-selectors, javascript-objects

I have a value stored in a variable. now I want to select the element whose value matches with the stored value. Here is the code

### HTML

```
<input type='radio' name='abc' value='a'>A<br>
<input type='radio' name='abc' value='b'>B<br>
<input type='radio' name='abc' value='c'>C<br>
<button>click me!</button>
```

### JS That is not working

```
$('button').click(function(){
  var x="a";
  $('input[value=x]').attr('checked','true');
})
```

### JS that works

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('input[value='a']').attr('checked','true');
})
```

Can anyone point out the problem?

here is the code in codepen
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doEPLG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
$('button').click(function(){
var x='"a"';
$('input[value=' + x + ']').attr('checked','true');
})
```

You are trying to select an input object with value as 'x' rather than selecting the object with the value contained in the variable x. This should correct it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[value=x]')
```

In this line 'x' is interpretted as the value not the variable x if you want to interpret the value from the variable x you can do this :

```
$("input[value=" + x + "]")
```

Now the x should be considered as the variable x. Check this it may solve the issue